# Syntax error in python match case statement

Tags: python

I stumbled into a problem with match:

```
age=34
match age:
    case age>50:
        print("you are more than 34")
```

and I get the error invalid syntax for the > symbol
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the 'if' keyword specifying the condition.

```
age = 30
match age:
    case value if value > 50:
        print("you are more than 34")
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [the `match` statement tutorial, conditional filters](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-conditions-to-patterns), as opposed to *matching*, is performed by postfix checks. In this case, you want:

```
anyname = 34

match anyname:
    case age if age > 34:
        print("you are more than 34")
```

This won't do anything as written (because 34 is not greater than 34), but if `anyname` were a number greater than `34`, you'd get the expected output.

I changed the name outside the `match` to make it more clear that you're providing one expression to the `match`, and the `case` is capturing to a separate name which it then performs the conditional check on. I also changed the check to make it make sense; if I'd used `age > 50`, the message produced by `print` would be nonsensical (it would only say you were more than 34 if you were more than 50).

Comment: And for the OP, please don't use `match` as a replacement for `if/elif/else`.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, `age>50` is not a legal case [pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#patterns).  (Match [tutorial](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) is better for learning.)  This seems close to what OP wrote.

```
for age in 25, 40, 65:
    match age:
        case n if 60 <= n:
            print(f"{n} is old")
        case n if 35 < n < 60:
            print(f"{n} in middle-aged")
        case _:
            print(f"{n} is young")
```

Match is designed for structure matching, rather than value matching.  The above would be better as an if-elif-else statement.

PS This, like nearly all questions about *Python* syntax and code, has nothing to do with IDLE.  Hence the edits.